# Why won't this simple messagebox work?

Tags: vb.net

```
Module Module1
    Public cccounter = 9
End Module

Public Class frmNim

    Private Sub btnSelect_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
        MsgBox(cccounter)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Why does this generate errors? I can't figure out any other way to make a simple counter go up by clicking on a button. This is frustrating me to no end. Is there something very simple that I'm obviously missing?

Comment: What type of error you are getting? No, comments on errors.

Comment: It's also good practice to trun "Option Strict" and "Option Explicit" in your VB.NET projects. That way, you will have to specify a type (a good thing) such as Public cccounter as Integer = 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `MessageBox.Show(ccounter)`

I think you're using the old VB6 coding. This won't work in VB.NET.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx)

If you need your counter to go up, you do need an extra line of code:

```
ccounter += 1
```

EDIT:

Missed the declaration in the module (VB.Net bit rusty now a days)

You should declare the ccounter as a variable as mentioned by @Eddie Paz)
I've made a quick sample that adds 1 at every click on the button.

```
Module Module1
    Public ccounter As Integer = 9
End Module


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ccounter += 1
        MessageBox.Show(ccounter)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That did not make a difference

Comment: Also, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on the .Net 4.0 Framework. It's VB.net

Comment: I wrote a quick VB.Net app in VS2010/4, and my code works. The message box shows cccounter as 10. What value are you getting?

Comment: And yes, the result is the same obviously :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring cccounter as a variant in Module1. You should specify the type such as integer. In the btnSelect:

```
cccounter = cccounter + 1
MessageBox.Show(cccounter)
```

I think MsgBox still works in VB.Net, but I don't remember. I try to use the .NET way now.

Comment: Didn't know MsgBox was deprecated. But yes, it still works in VB.net

Comment: Also, this doesn't work. You didn't really give any suggestion, you just told me to specify the type which I tried.

Comment: I'm sorry, this error was actually caused by something completely unrelated to the code I posted. There was no way you could've answered my question. The debugging didn't point towards that at all....

Comment: MsgBox is not depreciated. Both MsgBox and Windows Forms MessageBox and WPF MessageBox call the Windows API function MessageBox. All three are the .NET way.